# How to serialize custom SOAP for OTRS

Tags: c#, soap, otrs

There is a WSDL scheme for SOAP in OTRS, unfortunately with an automaton (connecting links), it does not work, because Sharp considers the file to be incorrect. for normal operation, you must obtain the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tic="http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/">
 <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
  <SessionCreate>         
          <tic:UserLogin>ULogin</tic:UserLogin>         
          <tic:CustomerUserLogin>CustUser</tic:CustomerUserLogin>         
          <tic:Password>ULPassword</tic:Password>
  </SessionCreate>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tried through `System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap` as follows:

```
  [Serializable]
  public partial class Envelope
  {
      /// <remarks/>
      public object Header { get; set; }

      /// <remarks/>
      public EnvelopeBody Body { get; set; }
  }
   [Serializable]
  public partial class EnvelopeBody
  {     
     public SessionCreate SessionCreate { get; set; }
  }
  [Serializable]
  [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapType(IncludeInSchema =true, Namespace = "")]
  public partial class SessionCreate
  {

      /// <remarks/>
      [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElement("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/")]
      public string UserLogin { get; set; }

/// <remarks/>
      [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElement("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/")]
      public string CustomerUserLogin { get; set; }

/// <remarks/>
      [System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElement("http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/")]
      public string Password { get; set; }

  }
  class TEST
  {
    void GetSoap()
    {
 var model = new SessionCreate
    {
        UserLogin ="ULogin",
        CustomerUserLogin="CustUser",
        Password="ULPassword"
    };

    var en = new Envelope
    {
        Body = new EnvelopeBody
        {
            SessionCreate = model
        }
    };
     SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    formatter.Serialize(ms, en);
    Console.WriteLine(StreamToString(ms));
    }
    string StreamToString(Stream stream)
      {
          stream.Position = 0;
          using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
          {
              return reader.ReadToEnd();
          }
      }
  }
```

As a result, it displays the following:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
 <a1:Envelope id="ref-1" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/OTRS.Request/OTRS%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull">
 <_x003C_Header_x003E_k__BackingField xsi:type="xsd:anyType" xsi:null="1"/>
 <_x003C_Body_x003E_k__BackingField href="#ref-3"/>
 </a1:Envelope>
 <a1:EnvelopeBody id="ref-3" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/OTRS.Request/OTRS%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull">
 <_x003C_SessionCreate_x003E_k__BackingField href="#ref-4"/>
 </a1:EnvelopeBody>
 <a1:SessionCreate id="ref-4" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/OTRS.Request/OTRS%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull">
 <_x003C_UserLogin_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-5">ULogin</_x003C_UserLogin_x003E_k__BackingField>
 <_x003C_CustomerUserLogin_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-6">CustUser</_x003C_CustomerUserLogin_x003E_k__BackingField>
 <_x003C_Password_x003E_k__BackingField id="ref-7">ULPassword</_x003C_Password_x003E_k__BackingField>
 </a1:SessionCreate>
 </SOAP-ENV:Body>
 </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The question arises, how to do it normally, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The best way to learn is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Compare the request made with a working application against the c# application that is not working.  Then make the c# app look like the working application.

Comment: @jdweng I know what the query should be (see the first sample code given), the question is how to bring it to it using serialization?

Comment: The URL of tic is "http://www.otrs.org/TicketConnector/".  So the namespace in the attribute above the class SessionCreate must have the same URL.